# linear ill-conditioned problems using sklearn.linear_model.Ridge - best way to describe training data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, inverse

Problem statement: I'm working with a linear system of equations that correspond to an inverse  problem that is ill-posed. I can apply Tikhonov regularization or ridge regression by hand in Python, and get solutions on test data that are sufficiently accurate for my problem. I'd like to try solving this problem using sklearn.linear_model.Ridge, because I'd like to try other machine-learning methods in the linear models part of that package (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html). I'd like to know if using sklearn in this context is using the wrong tool.

What I've done: I read the documentation for sklearn.linear_model.Ridge. Since I know the linear transformation corresponding to the forward problem, I have run it over impulse responses to create training data, and then supplied it to sklearn.linear_model.Ridge to generate a model. Unlike when I apply the equation for ridge regression myself in Python, the model from sklearn.linear_model.Ridge only works on impulse responses. On the other hand, applying ridge regression using the equations myself, generates a model that can be applied to any linear combination of the impulse responses.

Is there a way to apply the linear methods of sklearn, without needing to generate a large test data set that represents the entire parameter space of the problem, or is this requisite for using (even linear) machine learning algorithms?

Should sklearn.model.Ridge return the same results as solving the equation for ridge regression, when the sklearn method is applied to test cases that span the forward problem?

Many thanks to anyone who can help my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer through trial and error. Answering my own question in case anyone was thinking like I did and needs clarity.

1. Yes, if you use training data that spans the problem space, it is the same as running ridge regression in python using the equations. sklearn does what it says in the documentation.
2. You need to use fit_intercept=True to get sklearn.linear_model.Ridge to fit the Y intercept of your problem, otherwise it is assumed to be zero.

If you use the default, fit_intercept=False, and your problem does NOT have a Y-intercept of zero, you will of course, get a bad solution.

This might lead a novice like me to the impression that you haven't supplied enough training data, which is incorrect.

Comment: But by default the fit_intercept is set to True in sklearn Ridge.